# Open Port 123 to change Server time

Tags: centos, iptables, port

How can I actually open port 123 on my CentOS server, so I can synchronise my server with another server's time?

I couldn't be able to open 123 port using google guides.

Comment: What makes you think it's closed?

Comment: It is closed because I always got the message, that Operation is not permitted, wehn I want to update it with NTP

Comment: Sounds like you're not `root`

Comment: But I am the root. I can access everything. I have accessed it via SSH and with the root pass.

Comment: the answer is: you can't run ntpdate if ntpd is running. Either check if ntpd is synchronized running ntpq -p , or stop ntpd - service stop ntp - and run ntpdate

Answer (score 2):

In `iptables`

**To open OUTBOUND**

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 123 -j ACCEPT
```

**To open INBOUND**

```
iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport 123 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Where should I insert this? Also in which format should I enter these information?